# Как авторизироваться на сайте grailed.com через Requests?

Tags: python, requests

Нужно авторизироваться на сайте grailed.com с помощью библиотеки requests, но проблема в том, что при авторизации на данном сайте отправляются не только эл.адрес и пароль, но и recaptcha_token, который всегда обновляется, можно ли как-то спарсить этот токен? Ошибка 401

```
data = {
email: "example@gmail.com"
password: "example"
recaptcha_token: "Сам токен"
recaptcha_type: "invisible"
}

import requests
s = requests.session()
url = 'https://www.grailed.com/api/sign_in'

headers =  {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36'}

data = {"email":"example@gmail.com","password":"example","recaptcha_token": "example", 
"recaptcha_type":"invisible"}

r = s.post(url, json = data, headers = headers)

print(r.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробовал по-быстрому GET запросом получить html и вытянуть оттуда нужный токен.

```
html = s.get(url, headers = header, cookies)
```

И у меня ничего не получилось. Ошибка доступа. Попробуйте поиграться с header/cookies, но скорее всего придется использовать Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Ну и копать дальше, что вам нужно.
Например:

```
# Находим нужные элементы
username = driver.find_element_by_name("login_username")
password = driver.find_element_by_name('login_password')
continue = driver.find_element_by_name('login')

# Вставляем логин/пароль и кликаем на кнопку авторизации
username.send_keys("name")
password.send_keys("password")
continue.click()
```